# How do I iterate over a result set and add values to objects?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

In my main class I have a swing JFrame that opens, lets users select some options, and then calls another class. That class uses the info provided to post a query to SQL and get some values. I now want to add them to a table on the JFrame.

It looks like the only way to display data in a table is by passing in a 2d object array. Obviously to do that I need to add the values to a 2d object array. This is what i have for it so far:

```
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, decodedUsername, decodedPassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    if (rs != null) {
        rs.last();    // moves cursor to the last row
        size = rs.getRow(); // get row id 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //column is the column name in sql
        column = rs.getString("propertyname");
        //value is the corresponding value
        value = rs.getString("propertyvalue");

        data[0][i] = column;
        data[1][i] = value;

        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

The above shows connecting to the database, then getting the number  of rows, then trying to add the values to the object array data.

My expected is that it prints the values in the database, the actual is this:

You got an exception.

> [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@13edc840

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over a `ResultSet`, use the following code:

```
ResultSet rs = ...
while (rs.next()) {
    // do something
}
```

The issue with your code is that, in your loop, you are incrementing `i`, and so are adding data to many elements in your array, but you are not iterating the pointer in your `ResultSet`. `ResultSet.next()` returns `true` if there are rows remaining, and **also** increments the pointer stored in the `ResultSet`.

Instead of using an `Object[]` to store data (which requires an index parameter), you can use a `List<Object>` and call `list.add()`. For example,

```
ResultSet rs = ...
List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    list.add(new Pair(rs.getString("column1"), rs.getString("column2")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. However, when I do that (```List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   while (rs.next()) {
       list.add(new Pair(rs.getString("propertyname"), rs.getColumn("propertyvalue")));
   }```) I get The method getColumn(String) is undefined for the type ResultSet

Comment: My mistake, getColumn is the wrong method name, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Ok, I tried replacing Column with String before but it now gives me the error The constructor Pair(F, S) is not visible

Comment: I used Pair as an example class, you can use whatever data structure you want as the type for the list, including String[] if you prefer

Comment: Oh dear, I've been an idiot :D Anyway, using String[] where Pair was tells me that The type String is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String> and wants me to remove the arguments

Comment: Check which package you are importing Pair from. If you use javafx.util.Pair it should work as expected. I stress though, the choice of Pair is simply because it is a simple class to hold 2 variables. You are proably better off creating your own class and using that to store results.